# How to print inout parameters?

Tags: d

How can I print inout parameters?

```
import std.stdio;

void main()
{
    foo(2);
    return;
}

inout(int) foo(inout(int) x)
{
    writeln(x);
    return x;
}
```

Compiler output:

```
c:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\..\..\src\phobos\std\conv.d(3881): Error: template instance Unqual!(__T4ImplTNgiZ) does not match template declaration Unqual(T)
c:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\..\..\src\phobos\std\stdio.d(757): Error: template instance std.conv.toTextRange!(inout(int), LockingTextWriter) error instantiating
c:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\..\..\src\phobos\std\stdio.d(1708):        instantiated from here: write!(inout(int), char)
x.d(11):        instantiated from here: writeln!(inout(int))
c:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\..\..\src\phobos\std\stdio.d(1708): Error: template instance std.stdio.File.write!(inout(int), char) error instantiating
x.d(11):        instantiated from here: writeln!(inout(int))
x.d(11): Error: template instance std.stdio.writeln!(inout(int)) error instantiating
```

Also, to!string doesn't work with the inout parameter.

Update: I've just found out (by trial and error) that the following works:

```
writeln(cast(const)x);
```

Is this the normal method or am I missing something?

Comment: Not helpful in finding a solution to your problem, but what do you want to achieve with the `inout` attribute in front of the return type? If this was a method, it would would mean that `this` would be declared as inout. In that case I'd rather do `int foo(inout(int) x) inout`, much like you would use `const` or `pure`. Since this is a free function, I assume you meant someting like `inout(int) foo(inout(int) x)`. But since `int` is a primitive type and will be copied anyway, you could as well leave it out. With compound/constructed types, this is a whole other story.

Comment: You are absolutely right, thanks, copied wrong code... What I wanted to achieve: just testing how inout return type changes according to inout parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a library bug, most likely in Unqual. I added it here: http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=10544